# Why does my function composition implemented by reduce returns a closure?

Tags: php, functional-programming, reduce, function-composition

I want to derive a composition function for n-functions from reduce/fold, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
$id = function ($x) {
  return $x;
};

$comp = function ($f) {
  return function ($g) use ($f) {
    return function ($x) use ($f, $g) {
      return $f($g($x));
    };
  };
};

$fold = function ($f, $acc) {
  return function ($xs) use ($f, &$acc) {
    return array_reduce($xs, $f, $acc);
  };
};

$compn = function($fs) {/* apply $fold here */};

$inc = function ($n) {
  return $n + 1;
};

$fold($comp, $id) ([$inc, $inc, $inc]) (0); // yields a closure instead of 3
```

I have the same function implemented in Javascript and it works. I use PHP 7.0.8 cli. I don't know much about PHP, so I am probably overlooking something.

Comment: Functional programming doesn't feel well in PHP as it doesn't feel well in JavaScript either. These languages simply were not designed for FP. It can be done, as you already found out, but it's a lot of code that requires a lot of tricks to push it into the direction you want. It is nice as an exercise but I wouldn't use it into production. At least in PHP, an equivalent OOP solution (probably with [fluent interface](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) is more readable and provides, more or less, the nice API you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$comp` is [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), and of course you discovered PHP's native `array_reduce` expects the function to accept multiple parameters – a quick application of `uncurry` takes *some* of your pain away, but you'll need to read on if you want to see how this can be improved overall ...

---

***in PHP's humble opinion...***

Using *uncurry* does the trick, but you'll probably end up disliking your program if all the functions are defined as `$`-named variables – I foresee lots of little problems using that style.

PHP has a [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) "type" which makes things a little more PHP-ish – user-defined functions (including higher-order functions) should be called using [*call_user_func*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and [*call_user_func_array*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

```
namespace my\module;

function identity ($x) {
  return $x;
}

function comp ($f) {
  return function ($g) use ($f) {
    return function ($x) use ($f, $g) {
      return call_user_func ($f, call_user_func ($g, $x));
    };
  };
}

function uncurry ($f) {
  return function ($x, $y) use ($f) {
    return call_user_func (call_user_func ($f, $x), $y);
  };
}

function fold ($f, $acc) {
  return function ($xs) use ($f, $acc) {
    return array_reduce ($xs, uncurry ($f), $acc);
  };
}
```

Now your `compn` with variadic interface works as expected

```
function compn (...$fs) {
  return fold ('comp', 'identity') ($fs);
}

function inc ($x) {
  return $x + 1;
}

echo compn ('inc', 'inc', 'inc') (0); // 3
```

But it works with anonymous functions too

```
$double = function ($x) { return $x + $x; };

echo compn ($double, $double, 'inc') (2); // 12
```

---

***functional code, modular program***

With your functions declared using `function` syntax, you can [import](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) them into other areas of your program

```
// single import
use function my\module\fold;

// aliased import
use function my\module\fold as myfold;

// multiple imports
use function my\module\{identity, comp, compn, fold};
```

And now you don't have to litter you code with `use`-blocks every time you want to use one of your functions

```
// before
$compn = function (...$fs) use ($fold, $comp, $id) {
  return $fold($comp, $id) ($fs);
};

// after
function compn (...$fs) {
  return fold ('comp', 'id') ($fs);
}
```

When it comes to debugging, undoubtedly the *named* functions will provide more helpful stack trace messages as well

---

***relevant but unimportant***

PHP has other reasons for adding the *callable* type, but ones I'm sure that don't concern you as they're OOP-related – eg,

class method calls

```
// MyClass::myFunc (1);
call_user_func (['MyClass', 'myFunc'], 1);
```

object method calls

```
// $me->myfunc (1);
call_user_func ([$me, 'myfunc'], 1);
```

Comment: Don't get me wrong, PHP's callable "type" is disgusting – it's reminiscent of JavaScript's `setTimeout` which accepts a string that can be used to lookup a function in the global environment – PHP doesn't allow you to pass named functions as arguments to other functions, so I don't know of a more practical way around this.

Comment: PHP's callable type also accepts namespaces in the string qualifiers lol –
 eg `'my\module\foo'` – but watch out if you're using double quotes! You must escape the slashes `"my\\module\\foo"` – gotcha after gotcha

Comment: _you'll probably end up disliking your program if all the functions are defined as $-named variables_ Jaaa, I do. But functions as strings are awkward too: `compn ($double, $double, 'inc')`. Anyway, that helped a lot, thanks!

Comment: PHP has reinvented awkward more times than I've overflowed the stack ^_^

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out: `array_reduce` calls `$f` as a multi-argument function. So I have to introduce another anonymous function:

```
$id = function ($x) {
  return $x;
};

$comp = function ($f) {
  return function ($g) use ($f) {
    return function ($x) use ($f, $g) {
      return $f($g($x));
    };
  };
};

$fold = function ($f, $acc) {
  return function ($xs) use ($f, &$acc) {
    return array_reduce($xs, function ($acc_, $x) use ($f) {
//                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      return $f($acc_) ($x);
    }, $acc);
  };
};

$compn = function($fs) {/* apply $fold here */};

$inc = function ($n) {
  return $n + 1;
};

echo $fold($comp, $id) ([$inc, $inc, $inc]) (0); // yields 3
```

And here is the reduce/fold wrapper to get a nicer API:

```
$compn = function (...$fs) use ($fold, $comp, $id) {
  return $fold($comp, $id) ($fs);
};

$compn($inc, $inc, $inc) (0);
```